# Is there a way to count integers in an array less than a given point without a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

Is it possible to count integers in an array that match a criteria (e.g. less than `n`) without a foreach loop?

```
$arr = range(0,100); // not always consistent 0,1,2,3...100.  Could be 1,1,3,5,25,6,10,100.
$n = 20;
echo countLessThan($n,$arr); // can this work without a loop?
echo countLessLoop($n,$arr); // works, with the help of a loop

// can you make this work without a loop?
function countLessThan($n,$arr) {
    $count = ?; // number of items in $arr below $n
    return $count;
}

// this works, but with a loop
function countLessLoop($n,$arr) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($arr as $v) {
        if ($v < $n) $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: you can't do this without if else statement inside a loop

Comment: You can sort the array and find the position of the number.

Comment: Is the array sorted? Or constrained in any way?

Comment: Why do you need to avoid a foreach loop?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a loop?

Comment: Is the goal here "efficiency", "cleverness", or "homework"?

Comment: Updated question to make clear that array is not equal to 0,1,2,3...n.  Could be mixed integers. And no, this isn't for homework. I guess school is back in session now though. The goal is efficiency, cleverness, better understanding of how php works.

Comment: @cars10, see updated question. Can't count on a range, so can't count on $n being in $arr.

Comment: I think you can use count() for that http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: @Ryan - without having an array sorted in a particular way - it's not possible. That's why data structures were invented. Sorted data structure provides you with means to spend less time finding the records. If you were to store the array in a hierarchy (parent > child) then you'd be able to do what you want. This way - no, you'll loop the array whether it's internally or via custom loop. What you described with your problem is actually B-Tree so you could look up some php b-tree solutions on google.

Comment: "Efficient": you need to look at every element if there is not some kind of structure to the data (e.g. sorted); at best you can hope to look at each element only once. "Cleverness": sort the data once, create cumulative density function - now you can find the answer to any question ("how many elements less than x") in a single operation.

Comment: @N.B. Sorting is just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One generic method can be use of `array_filter` function which creates an array of elements meeting some criterion (given as a function name)

for example to count number of elements in array bigger then 3 one can run

```
function test($x){
 return $x>3; 
}

$data = array( 1,2,3,4,5 );
echo count( array_filter( $data, 'test' ) );
```

which prints

```
2
```

But obviously - without any restrictions on criterion and/or array - any solution will use a loop "under the hood" (and provided answer also loops, but simply using language predefined functions).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry not array_map() but array_filter() like this:

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '5');
print_r(array_filter($array,"lessthen"));
function lessthen($val) {
    if ($val<4) {
        return $val;    
    }
    else return NULL;
}
```

will print:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

see more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: now it works just fine, you can change the <4 for <'any value you want'

Answer (score 1):

If sorting of the array is allowed:

*(sorting in itself of course is not always cheap and internally involves some loops anyway)*

```
function countLessThan($n,$arr){
  sort($arr);
  return array_search ($n,$arr);
}
```

otherwise:

```
function countLessThan($n,$arr){
  $a=array_slice($arr,0);
  sort($a);
  return array_search ($n,$a);
}
```

But, then again: *This only works, if* `$n` *is actually a member of* `$arr`, otherwise you will get a wrong result!

For cases, where `$n` is not part of the array you might want to try a tree-approach by picking a point in the middle of the original array, then checking whether the value is higher or lower than `$n` and then recursively repeating the process on the remaining half of the array. The recursion is over when the length of an array is 1. The position found is basically the number you are looking for.

Comment: Try this fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4x9-xrp (I added a few more elements to the array).